# Is there a way to have Xamarin unit test runners from different platforms use the same tests from a PCL?

Tags: android, ios, unit-testing, xamarin, nunit

Let's say I have a cross platform mobile app. It is built in the Xamarin framework and its architecture looks like this (somewhat simplified):

- iOS project
- Android project
- PCL that contains logic (shared layer)

The shared layer contains all business logic and the other two projects contain the platform specific ui implementations e.t.c.

I would like to test the shared layer using unit tests. To do this I added two test runners for both OS' like [this one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/) for iOS. Both the test runners use the NUnit framework.

The unit tests are in a separate PCL which also uses NUnit.

Now my question: Is there a way to make both runners use this PCL's tests so that the tests are kept in one place?

I spent a while looking online but didn't find much about this.

Below I tried to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

A class from the shared project containing logic that needs to be tested:

```
public class Logic
{
    // The method to test
    public int add(foo, bar)
    {
        return (foo + bar);
    }
}
```

The PCL that contains the tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SharedTest
{
    public void RunAll()
    {
        // Some magic code that runs all the below tests..
    }

    [Test]
    Add() {
        logic = new Logic();
        Assert.AreEqual(logic.add(1, 1), 2);
    }
}
```

The iOS runner class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LogicTest
{
    SharedTest st = new SharedTest();

    [Test]
    st.RunAll();
}
```

**Side note:** I am aware that one could just run the tests from the PCL and mock some platform specific functionality if necessary, but my boss prefers to use the runners without the mocking.

This questions purpose is only to know if it's possible to use the platform specific runners without having two identical sets of tests.

Also, if you have a different way, i'm open to that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing further research it could be possible, but I found a much easier way, with more advantages. The solution to my initial problem (not wanting the same code in two places), is using a Shared Project. Then you can reference it in the runner projects and all your test will show there.

Another benefit from using this is that you can also use the compiler directives (#if __ANDROID__ of #if __IOS__) to put code in there that needs some platform specific functionality:

```
#if __IOS__
using IOSApp;
#endif

#if __ANDROID__
using AndroidApp;
#endif
```

information about shared projects can be found here: [Xamarin shared projects guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're planning to to correctly, but let me give it a try.

First of all: Portable Class Libraries, which you want to use to host your tests, can't reference Shared Projects. In other words: You cannot test your Logic class within a PCL. That's a blind end here.

Second: You wrote it's all about business logic you want to test. If that business logic isn't coupled to the UI, which otherwise would be far from ideal, you could easily put it into a PCL and run your tests on any test-runner you'd like. You don't have to run it on the platforms you're building for, because it's *portable*.

The easiest and most flexible way would be to add a fully-featured .NET/Mono class library project, reference nunit and your business-logic-PCL-project, and run the tests with the test runner of your IDE (Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio, doesn't matter).

If you do need some platform-specific stuff or something that isn't supported by the PCL profile you're bound to, you can easily inject it.

Let's say you want to do something with time zones, where there is not support for it in PCL. Add an ITimeZone interface in your PCL, implement it in both your Android and iOS apps *or* a Shared Project, and inject the implementation at runtime into your logic (by hand or any library you prefer, I would suggest ninject).

Comment: I realize that my question is a little vague. The tests in the PCL are already working, though.. I think I failed to explain the situation correctly.

The logic is already in a PCL, which I already can (and have) test with the unit test PCL. My boss just prefers to run them on the platform specific runners, even though the test already work in this setup. 

So the problem that I'm trying to fix now is that those platform specific runners seem to need their own test classes which forces me to make two identical sets of tests.